# Avalon Hill Gladiator

Tags: avalon-hill

Recently got my hands on this old gem, but the rules are a bit vague on some points.

1. When doing the defence action, do I defend only that combat phase or all of them?
2. Do I need to specify what area I defend?
3. How does shield damage work?

Comment: For the future you should break this up into separate questions to ensure they can all be answered properly

Answer (score 2):

(Note: I'm using the [fan-revised and clarified rules](https://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/79303/fan-revised-gladiator-rules). If you feel these answers contradict official rules, please update your question with quotes from the appropriate sections of the rules.)

1. Just that phase. When doing special defense actions (Duck, Block, etc.), record the defense letter "during the Combat Allocation Step". Quoted bit implies that it's for that phase, since you do this each phase: "Each combat phase, gladiators allocate their CF for attack, defense, net attacks and escape"
2. You allocate CFs for attacks and defenses to specific body areas, yes. And then: "ATTACK RESOLUTION: Conduct each attack by declaring the target body area and the attack CF allocated, then subtract any defense CF allocated to the same body area."
3. From the Shield Damage section (12) :

   > When a gladiator suffers a shield hit (’S’ or ’S*’) from a
   >   non-net attack [see 9.6], add the Combat roll WHITE dice
   >   (2D6), the attacker’s ST, and the modified CF (+1 DRM for
   >   an ’S*’ result) for possible shield damage.
   >   NOTE: CF gained from a Weakened Defender do not modify shield
   >   damage rolls [see 9.4.7].
   >   12.2.1 Compare the result to the shield’s damage points
   >   (highest unchecked box) on the Shield Damage display [see
   >   3.14]. If the result is < the shield’s damage points, check
   >   off a number of shield boxes (right to left) equal to the
   >   shield damage result, minus the shield’s damage points [see
   >   3.18].
   >   12.2.2 If the shield edge (‘S*’) was hit [see 9.6], also add the
   >   Combat roll WHITE & BLACK dice (3D6) for shield drop.
   >   12.3 When the last shield damage point is checked off, the
   >   shield is battered useless, and must be discarded [see 13.1].
   >   12.3.1 If a ’P’ or ’H’ shield damage box is checked off, the
   >   defender suffers the appropriate CRT result [see 9.6].